# How to collapse Accordion when I click a Button in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I have linked the code sandbox link [Sample Accordion](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledaccordions-material-demo-forked-p1b5ux?file=/demo.js), I have just added a button so that each time when the button gets clicked the accordion should close (Only for the closing scenario it should work).

Any Help will be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dont see any tabs.

Comment: @mxmissile thats why i made a button to imagine it as tab, it would take time to recreate with tab, that's why while clicking a button to close the accordion.